# Python PIL with littlecms support on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-imaging-library

I'm having trouble setting up python PIL with littlecms support.  I don't see any good tutorials from my googling.

Here are my main questions:

- What is the name of the Ubuntu package that needs to be installed for
  littlecms?
- If necessary, which directory(ies) do I set the `LCMS_ROOT` variable
  to in PIL's setup.py?

This is the result I'm getting of just running `pip install PIL`

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using Ubuntu 12.04 32bit

Answer (score 4):

Installing LittleCMS in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install liblcms liblcms-dev liblcms-utils
```

Then, when installing PIL, it's probably best to install from source **but only if** `pip install PIL` **doesn't** list LittleCMS support as available (as in your question originally). If you do need to install from source:

You will need to find/add a `LCMS_ROOT = [path]` line in PIL's `setup.py` (this line should be near the `JPEG_ROOT` and `ZLIB_ROOT` lines, if not, add it), which is where you specify the path to LittleCMS.

The default install location for `liblcms` is `/usr/lib64` on 64-bit Ubuntu.

You might be able to get away with `LCMS_ROOT = None` if you've installed to a default location.

Once you've done this, try running `python setup.py build_ext -i` and in the output, you should hopefully see something like

`--- LITTLECMS support available`

then do `python setup.py install` and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thanks for your help @jozzas.  I edited my question above to highlight my specific questions, so hopefully it's more clear.

Comment: I've added the apt-get line you should need, I'll be interested to know if the PIL installer picks LittleCMS up automatically!

Comment: ok.  I tried the packages you listed above.  It's not picking it up automatically.

Comment: I just tried pillow and I'm getting `--- LITTLECMS support available`

Comment: Certainly give Pillow a try - it's a direct fork of PIL that follows their image functionality exactly, so you should have no problems using that.